# Android: addTextChangedListener not working well

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to react to the user typing inside an `EditText` so I used the `addTextChangedListener` method.
When the user types a single character the code of `onTextChanged` is running and everything ok.
So if for example the user types "a" then `onTextChanged` will begin to **run**.

But if the user types another character, for example b , onTextChanged  is not being called.

(the text in the EditText should be "ab" now)

The code:

```
  et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittextsearch);
  et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
  {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){}
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after){}
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
      {
          int i = 0;
          textlength=et.getText().length();
          arr_sort.clear();
          for(i=0;i<3;i++)
          {
              if(textlength<=your_array_contents[i].length())
              {
                  if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) your_array_contents[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                  {
                      arr_sort.add(your_array_contents[i]); 
                  }
              }
          }
          lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(GroupsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arr_sort)); 
      }

  });
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Calculate and log the String length of et in onTextChanged(),making other code commented for now.I think,there is problem in your code only.

Comment: @Hiral - I don't understand you. what do you mean in "Calculate and log the String length of et in onTextChanged()" what is the problem you see ?

Comment: @user370305 - look at my comment to Adil Soomro answer (the problem in the post is now fixed, but there is a small behavior problem (description in the comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code, What I could understand is, you want to filter the `ListView`.

Instead of doing filter by yourself you should use `listView.setFilterText(String)`.

Like this way:

add your adapter for first and one time.

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(GroupsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, your_array_contents));
```

and then add TextWatcher:

```
txtFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.length()==0){
            lv.clearTextFilter();
        }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setFilterText(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: This works great! manyh thanks!.
When I type "ab" than I see in the the button part of the screen the text "ab" (looks like a toast) [I'm not talking about the EditText].Do you know how to disable this ?

Comment: @Belgi: That is default behavior. We cannot change it.

Comment: @Adil Soomro - probably a silly question but what causes the message to apper ? because even when I filtered myself it still showed the text below

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```