# Android listview filter space

Tags: android, filter

i have problem with this project
when ever i press Space button, results in the list view disappears. how can i add space in search input without dismissing the listview contents ?

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String str = s.toString();
        if (adapter != null && str != null)
            adapter.getFilter().filter(str);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }
};
```

https://github.com/himaniahuja/CMUSVDirectory_Android

thank you

Comment: You're question has probably already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722728/android-listview-edittext-filter-space-button)

Comment: Can you say me what to do ? if i change to  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         String st = s.toString().trim();            
         CMUSVDirectoryActivity.this.filterText.getFilter().filter(st);
     }                                 aa cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Just change `String str = s.toString();` to `String str = s.toString().trim();` in your original code