# how to get space in edittext filter using custom listview? does it possible using simple adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter, simpleadapter

I have custom listview using simple adapter, Currently I have issue regarding filter that I have custom list data with numbers and characters in listview.

If I enter name then  its give one blank space the filter results gets disappear.

I have list data like name then number for example : NAME 123, Whenever I enter name then gives space in that edit text then results are gone and list-view gets disappears.

I have tried this on below link but they used Array adapter, So my question is is it possible only in Array adapter or I can used simple adapter?

- [Android listview edittext filter space button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722728/android-listview-edittext-filter-space-button/13611717#13611717)

If yes then how can I implement, kindly help. Advance thank you.

Comment: offcourse it is possible in one adapter, Post your code how are you comparing the values?

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
searchView.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                              KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}
});
addTextChangeListener();
```

**now create method addTextChangeListener**

```
 private void addTextChangeListener() {
 searchView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence query, int start, int before, int count) {

    query = query.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<CityDataModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();



    final CharSequence finalQuery = query;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Clear the filter list
            filteredList.clear();

            // If there is no search value, then add all original list items to filter list
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(finalQuery)) {

                filteredList.addAll(cities);

            } else {
                // Iterate in the original List and add it to filter list...
                for (CityDataModel item : cities) {
                    if (item.getCity_name().toLowerCase().contains(finalQuery.toString().toLowerCase())
                            ) {
                        // Adding Matched items
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Set on UI Thread
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // Notify the List that the DataSet has changed...
                    adapter = new SearchCityAdapter(SearchCityClass.this, filteredList);
                    recyclerSearchCity.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();


}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
 });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Adapter, you can just implements your adapter with android.widget.Filterable

Example Adapter,

```
public class AppAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AppHolder> implements Filterable {

    public static final String TAG = AppAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<App> mApps = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<App> mCurrentItmCopy = new ArrayList<>();

    private String currentFilter;

    private MyArrayFilter mFilter;

    @Override
    public AppHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View receiverView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.layout_row_apps, parent, false);


        return new AppHolder(receiverView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final AppHolder holder, int position) {
        final App data = mApps.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mApps.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new MyArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }


    private class MyArrayFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mCurrentItmCopy == null || (mCurrentItmCopy.size() == 0)) {
                mCurrentItmCopy = new ArrayList<App>(mApps);
            }

            ArrayList<App> newValues = new ArrayList<App>();
            if (prefix != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(prefix.toString())) {
                String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (App value : mCurrentItmCopy) {
                    String label = value.getLabel().toLowerCase();

                    if ((label.contains(prefixString)) && !newValues.contains(value)) {
                        newValues.add(value);
                    }
                }
                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            } else {
                results.values = new ArrayList<App>(mCurrentItmCopy);
                results.count = mCurrentItmCopy.size();

                mCurrentItmCopy.clear();
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            currentFilter = constraint.toString();

            if (results.count > 0) {
                mApps.clear();

                addAll((ArrayList<App>) results.values);

            } else {

                mApps.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<App> items) {

        if (items != null) {
            mApps.addAll(items);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 }
```

In the above Adapter instead of App, you can use your object.

You can call from your activity or fragment like this,

```
mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
```